# how to run main.js, cros.js and server.py at the same time on a server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, digital-ocean

I am a newbie. I don't have any idea about this. need your help. please help me!

I have **3 files main.js, cros.js, and server.py** and I want to run these files simultaneously on my **digital ocean server**. Locally I have to run each file of these files in different vs code windows. But I want to run these files on the static server.

please say me how to run these 3 files at the same time on the server automatically.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have [access to a remote terminal](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/connect-with-ssh/). There, for something trivial:

```
node main.js & node cross.js & python server.py &
```

This will run all three processes in the background. (You'll want to use `fg` to pull them to the foreground one by one and ctrl+c them.)

For anything more involved, you may want to use a process manager like [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).